# Joomla Multilanguage website has 2 URL and one of them has to be redirected to a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, joomla1.5

I have a Joomla website with 2 url
www.acb.be and 
www.atlantec.fr

These 2 url are both going to the same joomla website. Now client asks me to redirect www.atlantec.fr to the french version on the site, found on www.atlantec.fr/fr/

Provider (Hostbasket Telenet) is not able to help me.
I read lots of articles about changing my .htaccess, but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me out here please?

Check out my .htaccess on http://www.acb.be/htaccess.txt

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?atlantec\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.atlantec.fr/fr/ [R=301,L]
```

but that will always force the user accessing www.atlantec.fr to the french version.